# Will a Factory Pattern be a good decision on this scenario ? - If not what pattern do you suggest?

Tags: design-patterns

We are developing a basic back-end app where people can admin their News, Events, Home Page Highlights, etc...
The problem arrives on the following scenario:

The client (a nursery garden for example) tell us: 
Beside News, Events, etc... I wish to also manage the Plants of this specific type unique on our Nursery Garden.

Of course we can well create a model for that on the back-office but, if we do so:

Issue 1) we have trash our application with some specific stuff that will, almost certainly, not be used by anyone else besides this client;

Issue 2) If 100 more clients arrive requesting 3 or 6 specific pages to be administrated, this trash get's event worst.

Can I please request what could be, on your opinion, a proper design pattern to apply here ?

Comment: If my question isn't a good one, please tell me so. Cheers.

Comment: `> Issue 1) we have trash our application with some specific stuff that will, almost certainly, not be used by anyone else besides this client;` Why would you trash it? Isn't it just a customer specific extension? Why do you have to modify everything else?

Comment: Thks. The goal of this apllication is to serve has model for a lot of clients. By that I mean, we will alocate resources do develop a feature that will worthless for 99% of the users. I mean, on that case, should we create a Database table for that specifc flower type for that user? And what about n other users? It seems that it woud more sense to me if we, somehow "build that" without the need to tweek the app each time a specific request is made... ?

Comment: So you are developing a SaaS aplication with a shared DB between all customers?

Comment: No. Good point. :) We will implement this "base application on each client, but either we tweek it for each implementation or not. But perhaps the best option will be to build a general propose app and, tweek as necessary regarding the client ? I was hopping for a more "automated solution that perhaps doesn't exist ? I've been told about "Plugin Framework" but, and since we may opt by one major framework like CI or Zend or Yii, the focus should be place on a "base apllication" that could be deployed? Care to advice, I'm fairly newbie on those matters. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you need some Dependency injection and a mechanism for it to be configurable. Look at IOC patterns and various IOC containers like windsor-castle, Ninject, Spring.Net, Unity ( for .net ).